# Checking for certain values in a range of numbers

Tags: c++, performance

Is there any chance to make this script run faster?The script goes through each number from `a` to `b`, and checks if it holds 1, if it holds 2, if it holds 3, if it holds 1 and 2, if it holds 1 and 3 and if it holds 1, 2 and 3. Then it saves all results.

```
unsigned long long a, b, f;

    a = 1;
    b = 100000000;
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 0, f3 = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, x5 = 0, x6 = 0, x7 = 0;   
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            f = i;
            while(f / 10 != 0) {
                if(f % 10 == 1) {
                    f1++;
                }
                if(f % 10 == 2) {
                    f2++;
                }
                if(f % 10 == 3) {
                    f3++;
                }
                f = f / 10;
            }
            if(f1 == 0) {
                if(f % 10 == 1) {
                    f1++;
                }
            }
            if(f2 == 0) {
                if(f % 10 == 2) {
                    f2++;
                }
            }
            if(f3 == 0) {
                if(f % 10 == 3) {
                    f3++;
                }
            }
            if(f1 > 0) {
                x1++;
            }
            if(f2 > 0) {
                x2++;
            }
            if(f3 > 0) {
                x3++;
            }
            if(f1 > 0 && f2 > 0) {
                x4++;
            }
            if(f1 > 0 && f3 > 0) {
                x5++;
            }
            if(f2 > 0 && f3 > 0) {
                x6++;
            }
            if(f1 > 0 && f2 > 0 && f3 > 0) {
                x7++;
            }
            f1 = 0;
            f2 = 0;
            f3 = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Lop a couple 0's off the end of `b` and it'd run much faster.

Comment: Well, yes, but I need it to work with 1 and 9 zeros, so I must add one more.

Comment: Try to find repeated bits (`f % 10` and `f / 10`, the comparisons) and remove them (calculate once, use nesting and short-circuiting to compare less). Then try to figure out what *you* can do to make it faster and rephrase this as a more specific question (research and propose instead of asking someone else to do it for you).

Comment: I see only invariants in this code - just precompute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would tell you to restructure the while into a do-while. This will allow you to run at least one iteration of your loop (for one-digit numbers), THEN see if you need to repeat. That will in turn allow you to avoid the additional double-checks to make sure you weren't ignoring one-digit numbers (which are currently performed unnecessarily on any number > 10 that honestly doesn't have a 1, 2, or 3 in it).

Other than that, I would suggest you break early. Use booleans instead of ints: once you know you have a 1, 2, or 3, don't keep checking digits for those values (meaning if you have all three you can exit the loop entirely; for 1000000000000000123, you're done looping through the divide/modulo loop after checking just the first three digits).

Lastly, you're making checks you already know are false. You're first checking if f1 > 0, then regardless of that result you're checking if f1 and f2 are > 0. Instead, try nesting ifs; once you know f1 > 0 you can check if f2 is also > 0, while if f1==0 you don't have to check if f1 > 0 and f2 > 0 because you already know it can't be true. Similarly, if any digit of f is 1, then the same digit cannot be 2 or 3, so as soon as you know what a digit is, continue to the next digit.

Try this (you may have to define bool; older C++ specs do not have it built-in):

```
unsigned long long a, b, f;

a = 1;
b = 100000000;
bool[] z = new bool[3];
int[] x = new int[7];
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        f = i;
        do{
            var c = f % 10;
            // test the most likely thing first; most digits are NOT 1-3
            if(c > 3 || c==0) { } 
            //once you know the value (or know the value exists), stop testing
            else if(!z[0] && c == 1) {
                z[0] = true;
            }
            else if(!z[1] && c == 2) {
                z[1] = true;
            }
            else if(!z[2] && c == 3) {
                z[2] = true;
            }

            //this MAY be faster depending on proc architecture and compiler;
            //some CPUs have "arithmetic-in-place" instructions.
            f /= 10;                
        } while(f != 0 && !(!z[0] && !z[1] && !z[2]));

        if(z[0]) {
            x[0]++;
            if(z[1]) { //1&2
               x[3]++;
               if(z[2]) //1&2&3
                  x[6]++;
            }
            else if(z[2]) x[4]++; //1&3
        }
        if(z[1]) {
            x[1]++;
            //we have already checked 1&2 and 1&2&3
            if(z[2]) x[5]++; //2&3                 
        }
        if(z[2] > 0) {
            x[2]++;
            //we have already checked 1&3, 2&3 & 1&2&3
        }

        //this is for conciseness and may not work depending on your C++ spec
        z[0] = z[1] = z[2] = false;
    }
```

Comment: Cheers, it's workign alot faster ;)!

Comment: no need to change to a do-while loop. just change the condition to `f != 0`. results should be equivalent.

Comment: True, but then the while loop tests something you know will always be false before doing any work that could make it true. If the initial state could make the condition false then while is perfect; otherwise do-while will avoid an unnecessary evaluation.

Comment: I guarantee you no one is using a C++ without `bool`.  Perhaps you're thinking of C, where it was introduced in C99?  (And you need the header `stdbool.h` to get the name `bool`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could start by changing your chained `if`s to `switch` statements and avoid duplicate `%` computations:

```
switch (f % 10) {
    case 1: f1++;
        break;
    case 2: f2++;
        break;
    case 3: f3++;
        break;
    default: //
}
```

Even better would be to use an array instead of numbered variables. Then you could do something like:

```
farray[f%10 - 1]++; // index to the location of f# value
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use an array instead of many variables:

```
int f[4], x[10];
```

and replace the while loop with (f replaced with tmp):

```
while(tmp > 0) {
      if (tmp%10 <= 3) f[tmp%10] ++;
      tmp = tmp / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOur algorithm is based on the fact that it's easy to know if a number between 0 and 9 "holds" 1,2, or 3.
There are not many numbers which holds 1,2 or 3 between 1 and 99: 1,2,3 10 ... 33
I would try this:

== initialisation

int tab_hold_ones[100] : if x holds one than tab_hold_ones[x] =1 else tab_hold_ones[0] =0
int tab_hold_twos[100] : if x holds two than tab_hold_twos[x] =1 else tab_hold_twos[0] =0
int tab_hold_threes[100] : if x holds two than tab_hold_threes[x] =1 else tab_hold_threes[0] =0

== Loop:

```
f = i;

        while(f / 100 != 0) {
            two_last_digits = f%100 ;
            f1 += tab_hold_ones[two_last_digits];
            f2 += tab_hold_twos[two_last_digits];
            f3 += tab_hold_threes[two_last_digits];
            }
```

So for each i you will do twice less while(f) iterations. Then the question is to know if it is faster to make the lookup in the 3 small arrays than computing the 3 % .

If b is big enough you will certainly win a the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to find closed formulas to express x1, x2... x7 as functions of a and b, avoiding the need to loop on the whole range a..b.

The general idea is as follows:

Between 0 and, say, 3 there is a single integer having a 2.

Between 0 and, say, 53 there are ten integers having a 2 in the first place plus the one between 0 and 3. Total 11.

Bewteen 0 and, say, 453 there are one hundred integers having a 2 in the first place plus the 11 ones between 0 and 53. Total 111.

Bewteen 0 and, say, 1453 there are no integers having a 2 in the first place, plus the 111 ones between 0 and 453. Total 0111.

So the number integers between 0 and some number having at least a 2 is of the form 1110101..., with a one or a zero depending on the corresponding digit in the original number.

The count between a and b is just the count between 0 and b minus the count between 0 and a-1.

This solves the case for x1, x2 and x3.

I wouldn't be surprised if this reasoning can be extended to the remaining cases, but I have not tried.

Comment: Mh, my reasoning is wrong somewhere, but there must be closed formulas...